# How can I display an informative message in an Outlook draft mail window?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

How can I show a message like the "Follow up" and "Assign policy" do while composing a new email? (see the highlighted area in the screenshot)

After searching I could not find anything that to lead me in the right direction. It must be something not directly tied with just [Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869356.aspx)s as that area is available also in the [Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860356.aspx).[image].

The closest thing I found are [Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301(v=vs.120).aspx) but I would like to use the builtin area for this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [MailTips](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649091(v=exchg.150).aspx).

The Outlook object model (nor VSTO) doesn't provide anything for that. You may consider using [Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but they allow placing the form at the bottom of the inspector window.

[Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php) provides a layout for placing your forms at the top of the inspector windows:

[image]

And the last resort is to subclass Outlook windows using Windows API and create an adjacent window, see [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) for more information.